# problem when the file upload to github repository

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, github

[image]

usually i can push my file or folder to github repository ,  but usually I often upload in excess may be 5 to 8 times the upload in a day

Comment: Please paste command outputs as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by as the output suggests, files and folders that you do not have locally on your computer. To fix this simply run `git pull origin master` (that is if master is your branch)